# $\gcd(p, qx_1 + rx_2) = 1$ for primes $p,q,r \ge 2^k$ and $x_1, x_2 < 2^k$

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose I have three primes $p,q,r$ that are $\ge 2^k$ each.
Suppose I also have two values $x_1, x_2$ that are $< 2^k$ each.

I am wondering if it is the case that, for all such $p,q,r$ and $x_1,x_2$, we have $\gcd(p, qx_1 + rx_2) = 1$.

I was trying to come up with a counter-example and show that $\exists x_1, x_2$, both $< 2^k$, such that $qx_1 + rx_2 = p t$, for some $t$.
Since $q$ and $r$ are primes, I know that $\exists$ Bezout coefficients $(a,b)$, with $|a|=|b|\le |q|=|r|$ such that:

\begin{align}
aq + br &= 1
\end{align}

Then, I could note that:
\begin{align}
q(apt) + r(bpt) &= pt
\end{align}
...and set $x_1 = apt$ and $x_2 = bpt$, but they will not be less than $2^k$.

Is there a way to come up with a counter-example (or show this holds)?

Comment: $11,13,17 > 8 > 3,2$. $\gcd (11, 13\times 2 + 17 \times 3) = 11$.

Comment: More generally, pick $ q\equiv r \pmod{p}$ and $ x_1 + x_2 = p $. This gives us $ \gcd(p, qx_1 + rx_2 ) = p $.

Comment: Ugh, should've started with simple examples... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply taking $q$ to be a prime that is $-1\mod p$ and $r$ to be a prime that is $1\mod p$, we see that $x_1 = x_2 = 1$ work.

By Dirichlet's Theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, for every prime $p$ there are infinitely many $q, r$ that work, but a concrete example is $p = 3, q = 5, r = 7$ (and $k = 1$).

EDIT: In fact, if we take **any** three primes $p,q,r$ such that $2^{k+1}>q>p>r>2^k$ then by simply taking $x_1=p-r, x_2=q-p$ we have

$x_1 \cdot q + x_2 \cdot r = p \cdot (q+r) \equiv 0 \mod p$

And clearly $x_1, x_2 < 2^k$

Comment: Thank you! Could you still find such $p,q,r$ if I additionally require that $p,q,r < 2^{k+1}$?

Answer (score 0):

To get examples where $p,q,r$ are large and as close together as possible, while $x_1, x_2$ are as small as possible, let $p$ be any [balanced prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_prime) and let $q,r$ be the primes before and after it. Take $x_1 = x_2 = 1$. It's conjectured that there are infinitely many balanced primes, giving infinitely many such examples.

For example, $1103$ is a balanced prime, because it is the average of $1097$ and $1109$, which are the primes before and after it. So we get the example $\gcd(1103, 1097 + 1109) = 1103 > 1$.

Comment: Thank you! And I think you could still find such $p,q,r$ if I additionally required that $p,q,r < 2^{k+1}$?

Comment: The $p,q,r$ I found are definitely close enough to be sandwiched between two powers of $2$ (much closer than that, in fact) but it's an open problem whether there's infinitely many such examples. (The largest known balanced prime, from the Wikipedia article, will give us an example with three primes between $2^{35030}$ and $2^{35031}$.)